# Is <?> higher than all others in the Java wildcard subtype hierarchy?

Tags: java

I'm doing a review for a final tomorrow. I'm being asked to draw the subtype hierarchy of the following types. I want to make sure all the answers I've gotten are correct. I kept in mind generic rules regarding subtypes. Is this correct?

1. `List<?>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Object>`, `List<Number>`, `List<? extends Number>`, `List<? super Number>`
2. `Set<Integer>`, `List<String>`, `Object`, `Collection<Integer>`, `Collection<Object>`, `Collection<?>`

My drawing:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually rather complicated. See http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ207

Comment: thanks. i looked at the diagrams. but it just make me feel like my theory on it is correct. except i would probably move List<Integer> a little down in the map.

Would you say my imageshack pic correct?

Comment: The way you stated "I'm being asked to draw" makes it sound like you are doing homework as part of your review, which is one of the reasons I gave an indirect answer. In general, users avoid solving homework problems on stackoverflow (it's better to give hints that allow people to solve it themselves). I suggest either drawing a table like it does on that wiki page, and/or writing some Java code to determine whether one type is a subset of another. Good luck!